# Allignment of the content in TCM

Tags: 2011-sp1

The footer in the Page which should be alligned to the centre gets alligned to the left of the page sometimes and alligns back to the centre without doing any changes. 
Suppose when you check in IE the footer is centre alligned and at the same time when you check in Chrome it is left alligned. After some time if you check in both the browsers it is centre alligned.
Could someone please let me know what could be the cause of it?

Comment: Is this happening on the website or in CME? Can you please clarify in your question with more detail?

Comment: If it wasn't for the tag and maybe "TCM," this would read like an HTML and maybe browser question. Thanks for asking on Tridion Stack Exchange, but without more information, there's not much we can do to help with this. Please answer Vipin's questions, give background on your Tridion setup, and maybe share some code.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on if you've refreshed the pages and how you're using Tridion.

1. If you did *not* refresh the pages, something client-side is possibly changing your markup or styles (JavaScript and/or CSS). Or maybe it's something as simple as different browser/view sizes in a Responsive Web Design.
2. If it's not front-end code and you refreshed between changes, then someone likely published a change.